# RC Circuit - Differential equation (beginner question)

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistance

In a circuit like this one, I was wondering how could one etablish a differential equation:

[image]

Because the intensity splits at the node, we would have :

\$R.i_2(t)+R.i(t)+L\frac{di(t)}{dt}=E\$

But how to get rid of \$i_2\$?

Comment: How would you solve it just with the resistors (assuming there's no L)?

Comment: The equation you have is the sum of all voltages around a loop using current as variables. The circuit has two meshes (two "window openings"), therefore you need two loops to describe the circuit. So write another equation based on a second loop. Then you have another equation but it also brings in another variable i1(t). So finally you have to make use of the relationship of the 3 currents at the node for your third equation.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is established by the virtue of Kirchhoff's voltage law that net
"The directed sum of electric potential differences around a closed loop is zero." So therefore as taking this loop (E,R,R,L) is a closed loop law holds.

Now coming to eliminating i2 that can be done by forming a loop of(E,R,R).
And solving the set of equations.

TIP: Use can use Laplace transform for quicker solution